# Spark jobs are not running in the specified queue

Tags: apache-spark, queue, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I am running spark job written in Scala.

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("BigDataSparkInitialPoc")
conf.set("spark.yarn.queue", "Hive")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

The above code is not submitting my code into the queue called "Hive".
Instead the job is running in the default queue

I checked in Ambari Portal and made sure that queue is up and running.It is allocated 25% of the cluster resources.

Any Idea on this issue?

Comment: Did you try the `--queue` option with `spark-submit`?

Comment: yes I tried  --queue "Hive"

Comment: Which mode(`cluster`, etc) are you using?